# Android menu item background

Tags: android, menuitem, background-color

I want to change the menu item background beacuse I use black icons, but on some phones the default color of background is black or other dark color. I tried [this solution](http://www.android10.org/index.php/forums/43-view-layout-a-resource/195-customizing-the-options-menu-background) and it's worked but there was a little problen with it:
I have ten items and that's why I have a "More" item to show other options, but if I choose the More item (which is got the custom background) and after that I press back button, the item will be in the default state, default colors. What is the solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The style attribute for the menu background is `android:panelFullBackground`. It's not hackish like the other solution, so it's not as buggy.

Despite what the documentation says, it needs to be a resource (e.g. `@android:color/black` or `@drawable/my_drawable`), it will crash if you use a color value directly.

Comment: This is the correct way to do it. Using themes/styles & doing the most of customization in XMLs. You can get the attribute here : [panelColorBackground](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#panelColorBackground)  
A good integration example comes directly from the sources. Check out [themes on devdaily.com](http://www.devdaily.com/java/jwarehouse/android-examples/platforms/android-7/data/res/values/themes.xml.shtml) and [styles](http://www.devdaily.com/java/jwarehouse/android-examples/platforms/android-7/data/res/values/styles.xml.shtml)

Comment: @Pilot_51, hi, where should I apply the panelFullBackground style? I tried to apply it on menu, theme, and menu item, none of them worked

Answer (score 1):

try to use android own menu icon like as setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_search)

Comment: I have more custom icons which are don't included in the android :(