# I'm trying to change the background of a Menu item

Tags: android

I know this question has been asked many times. But from what I read, the method I'm trying should work.

I'm trying to follow the steps mentioned in [this link.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5206044/813207) Here is my code for it: (styles.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="Theme">
     <item name="panelFullBackground">@drawable/background</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

I'm getting an error that says:

```
No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'panelFullBackground'.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need change `panelFullBackground` to `android:panelFullBackground`