# how to translucent menu android

Tags: android, menu

Anyone know how to make a menu like this photo? If there is any tutorial or if you can give me a hint I'm thankful.

[image: example menu]

Comment: check these So posts ::  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944244/change-the-background-color-of-the-options-menu  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719173/change-background-color-of-android-menu  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5065828/android-menu-item-background

Answer (score 1):

You can created own menu class. Here is the article published and a downloadable link to the source code. Hope this link will be helpful to you.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/173121/Android-Menus-My-Way

Comment: uowwwwwwww my friend! very very very thks! ok? God bless you!

Comment: brother, almost this tutorial solved my problem. But the menu I want is one that does not need to press the menu button for it to appear. He is active all the time in the activity. can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

This menu is like a i-phone , you can download example of this menu from this  [Link 1](https://github.com/AdilSoomro/Iphone-Tab-in-Android)

it is looks like following image

[image]

Consider following links that may help you

[Link 2](http://www.anddev.org/code-snippets-for-android-f33/iphone-tabs-for-android-t14678.html)

[Link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7975255/1218762)